# Fill a column's blank spaces contingent on a second column in R

Tags: r, fill

I'd appreciate some help with this one. I have something similar to the data below.

```
df$A df$B
1    .
1    .
1    .
1    6
2    .
2    .
2    7
```

What I need to do is fill in `df$B` with each value that corresponds to the end of the run of values in `df$A`. Example below.

```
df$A df$B
1    6
1    6
1    6
1    6
2    7
2    7
2    7
```

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the missing values are denoted by `.`.  It is better to read the dataset with `na.strings="."` so that the missing values will be `NA`.  For the current dataset, the 'B' column would be `character/factor` class (depending upon whether you used `stringsAsFactors=FALSE/TRUE` (default) in the `read.table/read.csv`.

Using `data.table`, we convert the `data.frame` to `data.table` (`setDT(df1)`), change the 'character' class to 'numeric' (`B:= as.numeric(B)`).  This will also result in coercing the `.` to `NA` (a warning will appear).  Grouped by "A", we change the "B" values to the last element (`B:= B[.N]`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,B:= as.numeric(B)][,B:=B[.N] , by = A]
#   A B
#1: 1 6
#2: 1 6
#3: 1 6
#4: 1 6
#5: 2 7
#6: 2 7
#7: 2 7
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(A) %>%
     mutate(B= as.numeric(tail(B,1)))
```

Or using `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$B <- with(df1, as.numeric(ave(B, A, FUN=function(x) tail(x,1))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), B = c(".", 
".", ".", "6", ".", ".", "7")), .Names = c("A", "B"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: That did the trick - thanks for the N/A tip too! Much appreciated.